# how to destroy a cookie by php condition

Tags: php, cookies

I want to destroy the cookie by the php condition but i have not got anything to do that after the lots of research on the google and php manual . i have read at some place that `setcookie('cookie_name');` but it just erase the cookie so my question is that how to destroy cookie by php ?

Comment: What is your difference between erasing and destroying a cookie?
setcookie('name', false, 0); will remove it. I think thats your goal.

Comment: @D.Müller `0` for time will not erase the cookie, it means destroy when the browser is closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When deleting a cookie you should assure that the expiration date is in the past, to trigger the removal mechanism in your browser

```
setcookie ("cookie_name", "", time() - 3600); // set the expiration date to one hour ago
```

[**Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to erase a cookie in PHP perse. What `setcookie("cookie_name");` does is it instructs the browser to keep the cookie untill *now*, meaning that it can clean it up (you normally give it a date sometime in the future).

You can not force a cookie to be deleted.

If you need better control over what data is kept in the current session use server-side session storage. Keep only the `session_id` in the cookie.

Comment: Please also not that is you still try to access `$_COOKIE['cookie_name']` in the script after calling `setcookie('cookie_name')` it will still be available, so you might also need to do `unset($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])` if you don;t want the variable available to the remainder of the running script.

Comment: actually i want to create a text area where if user refresh the page and form is not submitted the last content in the textarea will be there ...like stackoverflow   for that i thought .to store in cookie is it ok to store in cookie

Comment: You could store that in the cookie, but then maybe you're better off implementing it in JavaScript?

Comment: @Lokesh What you are wanting to do is something that might best be done via AJAX, sending the data to the server to store in a session variable to be repopulated in case the user refreshes the page.

Comment: @Lokesh I think SO's is done by the browser actually, since if I use an old browser it doesn't save the text and I have noticed that Firefox does it with pretty much all sites. I don't use other browsers for more than testing my sites so I can't speak for them, maybe SO does have a JS plugin for this

Comment: Maybe SO uses client side storage? Or it just doesn't work for older browsers because their JavaScript engines are really bad!

Comment: @MikeBrant but i think it will generate extra lode ,consume space on server

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Lol prolly a bit of both, I haven't tested SO temp storage enough :P

Comment: @Lokesh Sure it will cause extra requests to be made against the server, but that it pretty much the price you pay to do really modern web application development. Actually client side (HTML5) storage may be your best bet.  Though you lose some browser compatibility.  This are the tradeoffs you have to consider in modern web application design.

Comment: @MikeBrant even i do want but there are [27% people using the window xp](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) withe the ie6 so i have to also think about them

Comment: @Lokesh Dude Google, Facebook, Youtube and many others don't care for IE6 anymore, let it die already, the 1b members of facebook cant use IE6 or 7 properly with the site. So honestly, let it die...I should also mention those stats are scewed, they are not a true representation of the internets usage of browsers or OSs

Comment: @Lokesh Infact IE9 still holds the market share according to global stats so those stats really are not very accurate and you will find those are based on the small number of sites Awio Web Services LLC has a counter on.

Comment: @Lokesh The OS is not important on the stats you gave.  Look at the browser usage. Less than 5% is on IE7.  In my company we have a higher % of users with older browsers because we have a lot of traffic from China, Indonesia, etc. and we gave up trying to support IE6 two years ago.  I don't think anyone in their right mind should be supporting IE6 unless the have a very specific use case (like developing for a company that only uses it).

Answer (score 1):

Destroying cookies is upto the browser however you can remove a cookie (which is the same for your app) by setting the date in the past:

```
setcookie($cookie_name, "", 1);
```

Most set the time to `1970`.

Ha! @MikeBrant makes a good point. Since PHP can't understand if `setcookie` was done to remove a cookie `$_COOKIE` is still set after issuing this command so you have to `unset` it.